# How to put the contents of a file to a String of array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a String array which contains some  records ,now i have to put that records in a file and have to read those values and have to check the records with the String array values.Here is my String array..

```
 public final static String fields[] = { "FileID", "FileName", "EventType",
        "recordType", "accessPointNameNI", "apnSelectionMode",
        "causeForRecClosing", "chChSelectionMode",
        "chargingCharacteristics", "chargingID", "duration",
        "dynamicAddressFlag", "iPBinV4AddressGgsn",
        "datavolumeFBCDownlink", "datavolumeFBCUplink",
        "qoSInformationNeg"};
```

I have to put these records in a map using these,,

```
 static LinkedHashMap<String, String> getMetaData1() {
  LinkedHashMap<String, String> md = new LinkedHashMap<>();
  for (String fieldName : fields) md.put(fieldName, "");

  return md;
```

}

now my file is

```
        FileID 
        FileName
        EventType
        recordType
        accessPointNameNI
        apnSelectionMode
        causeForRecClosing
        chChSelectionMode
        chargingCharacteristics
        chargingID
        duration
        dynamicAddressFlag
        iPBinV4AddressGgsn
        datavolumeFBCDownlink
        datavolumeFBCUplink
        qoSInformationNeg
```

Now i am reading this file with this function

```
static LinkedHashMap<String, String> getMetaData() {


    LinkedHashMap<String, String> md = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {

        String sCurrentLine;
        String file[];
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("./file/HuaGPRSConf"));

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {


         md.put(sCurrentLine, "");
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)
                br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    return md;
}
```

Now those two functions are returing values in two different ways..The String is giving

```
{FileID=, FileName=, EventType=, recordType=, accessPointNameNI=, apnSelectionMode=, causeForRecClosing=, chChSelectionMode=, chargingCharacteristics=, chargingID=, duration=, dynamicAddressFlag=, iPBinV4AddressGgsn=, datavolumeFBCDownlink=, datavolumeFBCUplink=, qoSInformationNeg=}
```

But the file from which one i am getting the values is giving values with a big spaces..

```
{            FileID =,             FileName=,             EventType=,             recordType=,             accessPointNameNI=,             apnSelectionMode=,             causeForRecClosing=,             chChSelectionMode=,             chargingCharacteristics=,             chargingID=,             duration=,             dynamicAddressFlag=,             iPBinV4AddressGgsn=,             datavolumeFBCDownlink=,             datavolumeFBCUplink=,             qoSInformationNeg=,             rATType=,             ratingGroup=,             resultCode=,             serviceConditionChange=,             iPBinV4Address=,             sgsnPLMNIdentifier=,             timeOfFirstUsage=,             timeOfLastUsage=,             timeOfReport=,             timeUsage=,             changeCondition=,             changeTime=,.... so on
```

now when i am trying to check two values using this function they are not equal..

```
LinkedHashMap<String, String> md1=getMetaData();
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> md2=getMetaData1();

    if(md1.equals(md2)){
        System.out.println(md1);
    }else{
        System.out.println("Not");
    }
```

i cannot understand the problem can anyone help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `sCurrentLine.trim()` to remove unnnecessary whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if 2 different instances of `LinkedHashMap` are equal and they are not.
You have to use `get` method of `LinkedHashMap` to compare values.

Also you should remove empty spaces by `String` `trim` method.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to first check the data before comparing.If , you are finding extra space then first apply `trim()` to remove the space and then compare.